# Textarea dynamic variable

Tags: php, html, textarea

I want to define dynamic variables from a textarea

```
<form>
<textarea name="dynamicText">Hello my name is [name]</textarea>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Php Code Example

```
$text = $_POST['dynamicText'];
$name = "John Doe";
// i need some function ...
echo $text;
//Output --> Hello my name is John Doe
```

The output i want

```
Hello my name is John Doe
```

Comment: where do you find the name?

Comment: and fix **texteare**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['hello'])){
    echo $_GET['textarevalue'];
  }

?>

  <form action="" method="get">
     <textarea name="textarevalue"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" name="hello"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: no i want after submit
i want submit email i need regex or A function that can perform the same function

Comment: it means you want to get textarea value after submit button clicked?

Comment: Yes i want after submit

Comment: whole textarea value or just [name] in textarea?

Comment: all textarea value

Comment: Your question doesn't match your solution. Anyway good to hear that its sorted. mark your question as solved

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
  // store your dynamic name into variable
  $name = "John Doe";
?>
// show like this 
<form><texteare>Hello my name is <?php echo $name; ?></texarea>
```